# Move individual midi notes to the end of each note in Logic Pro X

Tags: midi, logic-pro

Is there a function or method of moving a set of midi notes to their individual end note positions in Logic Pro X?

Ie. midi note A with length 10 should be moved to its end position (11), and midi note B with length 5 should be moved to its end position (6).

What I want to achieve is basically to have a midi note in the position of every keyboard release/lift. Keeping each note’s original length is not important.

Comment: I don't use Logic, but it has a Transform page similar to that in Cubase, so.. the workflow would be "for all note-off, generate note-on with position +1, duration unchanged". As many instruments don't really use note off, you may find you need to use note-on=0 & impose a fixed velocity to the output.

Comment: @Tetsujin man, that sounds exactly like what I want, but I’ve had no luck trying to get it to work in the midi transform feature. I will continue though…

Comment: Not something I've ever tried before, but just tested in Cubase. It was simpler than I first thought -  'Filter target - all notes; Action target - Position, Add length, then Position, add 0.0.0.1... then Transform'. Done. So, in effect I move the notes as-is, so all other data stays as original, inc velocities etc. https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hYZ.png

Comment: It might be possible to use the MIDI Scripter to change your MIDI messages in real-time, with some JavaScript code. You could then even record from one track to another using the environment. Not quite sure how all this would be done, but I’ll have a think...!

Comment: You could do the process @Tetsujin describes, create a MIDI ON whenever a MIDI OFF is read. And bypass the MIDI on messages.

Comment: There are quantization and note position features in Logic that are much easier to use than the confusing MIDI transform panel. You can quantize note endings in the quantization settings if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want each chord/note to perfectly connect to the next chord/note. In order to do this, select your notes or chords in the MIDI editor, then press Shift + Backslash.